# CLLocation Timestamp is always zero

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

The CLLocation timestamp is always zero on iPhone 6+, IOS 11.4, Xcode 9.4.1.

Latitude: 30.598748
Longitude: -97.820877
Altitude: 308.921658
HAccuracy: 10.000000
VAccuracy: 4.000000
Timestamp: 0.000000  <======

Is there some setting that will give me accurate timestamp? Here is the code that prints it:

```
print("Latitude: \(String(format: "%.6f", location.coordinate.latitude))")
print("Longitude: \(String(format: "%.6f", location.coordinate.longitude))")
print("Altitude: \(String(format: "%.6f", location.altitude))")
print("HAccuracy: \(String(format: "%.6f", location.horizontalAccuracy))")
print("VAccuracy: \(String(format: "%.6f", location.verticalAccuracy))")
print("Timestamp: \(String(format: "%.6f", location.timestamp as CVarArg))")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `timestamp` is an object of type `Date`. It should print with this:

```
print("Timestamp: \(String(format: "%@", location.timestamp))")
```

Comment: Or simply: `print("Timestamp: \(location.timestamp)")`.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you. I don't trust my Swift `print` skills since it started giving all those warnings about string interpolation.

Comment: Thanks for seeing that...copy and paste always gets me.